# Is there any reason to do .fit() and .transform() instead of just .fit_transform()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I just started learning ML and wondered why one would do `.fit()` and `.transform()` separately, when `.fit_transform()` exists. Also, I am generally confused on what exactly fitting/`.fit()` does.

Comment: Maybe you want to `transform` many datasets with the same fitted transformer.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models

Comment: @timgeb What exactly does that mean/could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about sklearn's scalers or sklearn's feature transformation algorithms in general.

Let's say your dataset is splitted in 5 sub-sets and you want to scale each of them between -1 and 1:

- You fit your scaler on each sub-set using `fit`, this basically searches for the maximum and minimum over all of your sets
- Then, you can scale your sub-sets using `transform`

If you had used `fit_transform`, on the first sub-set, then used it on the second one, it would have been scaled differently, and you don't want that.

Moreover, instead of sub-sets, you can think of fitting once on your training set and keeping the transformation in memory to scale future samples you want to pass to your model.